# How to convert a word in regex uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am working with Postgres DB and need to convert a text for a regex that accepts uppercase and lowercase in any letter, for example:

transform palaver "wOrD" in [Ww] [Oo] [Rr] [Dd]

I am trying unsuccessfully to the command:

```
SELECT regexp_replace ('wOrD', '[a-zA-Z]', '[Ww]', 'gi');
```

Comment: what is the desired output for a given input?

Comment: I need to use a command " **select col from table where col_txt similar to '%(wOrD)%'** ", but i dont know if "word" is upper, lower or mixed. i need a regex command.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother adding character classes per each letter, and would use the inline modifier `(?i)`:

```
SELECT regexp_replace ('wOrD', '^', '(?i)');
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7754a/4)